# ¿Cómo cambiar los bordes de un elemento a medida que se completan los input?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Estoy tratando de lograr que los bordes un elemento cambien de color a medida que voy completando los input de un formulario. Lo he logrado a medias con el siguiente código, debido a que solo funciona en una determinada secuencia, si completo los input de arriba hacia abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
let inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
let imgLog = document.getElementById('content-logo');
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('input',changeLogo);
}
function changeLogo (){
    if (inputs[0].value!=0) {
        imgLog.style.borderBottom = "4px solid red";
        if (inputs[1].value.length!=0){
            imgLog.style.borderRight = "4px solid red";
            if (inputs[2].value.length!=0){
                imgLog.style.borderTop = "4px solid red";
                if (inputs[3].value.length!=0){
                    imgLog.style.borderLeft = "4px solid red";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pon cada `if` después del anterior en lugar de anidarlos.

Comment: Como te comentan, de ese modo cada if depende del anterior y si no se cumple la condicion previa no va a cambiar de color. En todo caso puedes usar switch o poner los if separados. Y si quieres mas colores puedes jugar con la opacidad para que si tiene mas de un imput completo se multipliquen.